# Duplicate entry for key primary in many to many relationship table

Tags: mysql, exception

I get this exception:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO my_table 
(uid_local, uid_foreign) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [37127, 49889]:

Duplicate entry '49889-49889' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

However, the primary key is defined as `(uid_local, uid_foreign)`:

[image: Primary key definition]

Shouldn't be the key entry '37127-49889' anyway?  And yes, the combination 37127-49889 would be unique; there is no entry for uid_local=37127 at this time and only one for uid_foreign=49889.

Comment: Do you have any triggers associated with the table?

Comment: @Barmar No, it's a very basic table. Just uid_local and uid_foreign, which build the primary key. Nothing else.

Comment: Maybe there's a corrupted index, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31701/finding-and-fixing-innodb-index-corruption

Comment: Just to check for subtle things:  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table` and `SELECT * FROM my_table`.